Docker swarm join connection refused
In short:
I want a second machine on the same LAN network to join the docker swarm but it keeps failing with error "connection refused". Please help me ;)
A little longer:
I have 2 windows machines, both running Docker desktop and I am trying to get machine 1 as manager and machine 2 as worker in a docker swarm.
machine 1 has ip: 192.168.1.102
machine 2 has ip: 192.168.1.103
Both machines are on the same network and have the same subnet mask and gateway I Added on both machines inbound and outbound rules to allow ports:

TCP: 2377 and 7946
UDP: 7946 and 4789

Attempt 1 to join via powershell on the second machine
docker swarm init output from console:
docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-3b9cxew98787g82elx0vm8uqc72ol2nykmfad34zf5jmljb832-7gaqy8fthak0v0uzoufcxnwiz 192.168.65.3:2377

If I try this command on machine-2 it fails with "connection refused"
Attempt 2:
docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.1.102 --listen-addr 127.0.0.0:2377

output from console:
docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-5415kg2nztzyjur50jy4byxvo2wbewnfennmzieck53xeatcdw-94y9bzxnemxaf2kjx8pvue53v 192.168.1.102:2377

If I try this command on machine-2 I get Connection timeout => and when inspecting via docker info I see it states "connection refused" => so the same
I also tried this with firewalls disabled on both machines.
When I try to ping from machine 2 to machine 1 (ping 192.168.1.102) I get a timely response.
So my question is: This should be stupidly simple: How can I create a swarm which is joinable by another node on the same subnet, both on windows machines running Docker in WSL mode.
Thank you in advance!

To quote the [tag:docker-swarm] tag description: "Questions about creating and configuring a Swarm cluster are OFF TOPIC FOR STACK OVERFLOW." Your question may possibly be on-topic on https://superuser.com or https://serverfault.com though.
